# Unable to upload Files Using Multer React Js And Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

[Attaching Documents Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqFEj.png)
As shown in the pic i am attaching my documents.

```
onDrop: (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
      if (rejectedFiles.length) {
        toast.error('You can upload images , Words and Excel files !.')
      } else {
        console.log(acceptedFiles)
        setFiles([...files, ...acceptedFiles.map(file => Object.assign(file))])
      }
    }



axios.post('http://localhost:5000/AddEmployee', {
  user, employeeDocuments : user[2].documents
    })
      .then(res => { 
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch(err => { 
        console.log(err) 
      })
```

I am storing all test documents in the employeedocuments array and then i am sending post request to backend.

[employeeDocuments array in console log view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QGkd.png)

Here i am console log the employeeDocuments array it is looking fine.

```
enter code here

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "./public/uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});


var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
 
var uploadMultiple = upload.fields([{ name: 'employeeDocuments', maxCount: 10 }])
```

This is my backend multer code to upload files i have used the name employeeDocuments to upload files but multer is not uploading these files.Rather i used postman and it was working fine. But when i upload these files using react by post request these files not get uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and I was able to fix it by modifying my axios post request to sending Form Data:

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('imagePath', image)
```

The have the upload in the post like this: `router.post("/AddEmployee",upload, async (req, res)`
And store it in the DB as a path using `req.file.path`

Sorry if its a bit confusing but this is everything I have in my code and its fully working

Comment: I have used formdata also but files are not getting uploaded. And when i console log the req.files  the  output is [Object: null prototype] {}

Comment: Thanks Issued resolved it is actually not taking the whole employeeDocuments array  so i used for loop and loop through employeeDocuments array and append each file obj in formdata as employeeDocuments name. And It worked fine .